# Adding an "m" to the end of every number in a row

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

What function do i need to use to add an space and an m after every item in a row, using the field calculator in the attributes table. I have a load of numbers (as strings) and would like to add m after each one

Comment: Is this solely for labeling purposes? Not sure about QGIS, but in Arcmap you can add a string to every label without it being in a field.

Comment: It will be purely for labelling. It will be exported in Illustrator with these numbers showing as altitudes but with an m after each one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the field calculator select "update the column" where you have numbers and use this string

```
 "COLUMN_NAME"  || ' M'
```

If you just want to label them with the 'M' paste the same code in the "expression based label panel".